# Formatting strings in C

Tags: c, string-formatting

I was wondering how I could format the print statement in a C printf to have 4 spaces before the letter. Where the space position is predetermined by a variables

```
int spaces = 4;
printf("Four spaces before the sentence gets printed")
```

output would like

```
"    Four spaces before the sentence gets printed"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` format specifier can take width as `int` value:

```
printf("%*s%s", 2, "", "Test");
```

prints

```
  Test
```